# Do you know any flex component with the functionality such as horizontally collapsible window or panel

Tags: apache-flex, components

Do you know any flex component with the functionality such as horizontally collapsible window or panel

I found arc90, but it folds vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the HAccordian in FlexLib?

http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/wiki/ComponentList

http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/HAccordion_Sample.swf